# DATE_SUB return date in specif format

Tags: mysql, sql, date-format

Part of my SQL query

```
DATE_SUB(dStartDate,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS dEarlyBirdExipiryDate
```

It return dEarlyBirdExipiryDate as `2013-05-16`

But I want it in `16 May, 2013` format.

What changes I should make in my query to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( DATE_SUB(dStartDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                   , '%d %M, %Y'
                  )  AS dEarlyBirdExipiryDate;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/12320)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this. Em not sure but it would work with a few tweaks.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(DATE('2007-11-30 09:00:00'),  INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d %M, %Y'); //
```